# PostgreSQL URL Not Found When Attempting To Connect With Java

Tags: java, sql, database, postgresql, jdbc

I am trying to connect to my postgresql database using Java. I have done this successfully before, but I don't know what is going wrong this time, here with my URL.

```
Connection conn = connDriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/users", "loginName", "password")
```

I am certain this database "users" exists. The spelling is correct and it contains tables.

Any ideas why an sqlexception is being thrown?

Here is more of my connecting class...

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Enumeration;

import org.postgresql.Driver;

public class PostgresHelper {
    private Connection conn = null;

    public void connect() throws SQLException {
        connect("localhost");
    }

    public void connect(String host) throws SQLException {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/users", "loginName", "password");
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        return conn;
    }
    public void close() throws SQLException {
        if (conn != null) {
            conn.close();

            conn = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you paste the error message?  A couple of  notes: the connect method is passing in a "host" parameter but it is not used in the url. The "conn = DriverManager" should be within the "try" block, otherwise you will attempt to connect when there is no driver. Also, if the new driver is on the classpath, I don't think you need "Class.forName" anymore since the service locator is used.

Comment: What is the **exact** exception that you get? And Glenn is right. You should rather put the `getConnection()` into the try block. The `Class.forName()` is not necessary

Comment: HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

java.lang.NullPointerException
 com.micylt.webproject.Project.DAO.UserInfoDAO.emailExists(UserInfoDAO.java:151)
 com.micylt.webproject.Project.userinfo.controller.UserInfoController.newUser(UserInfoController.java:115)
 com.micylt.webproject.Project.userinfo.controller.UserInfoController.

Comment: It looks like I'm getting back a null connection for some reason...